# git create stash without need to configure user.email and user.name (git stash --author ?)

Tags: git, git-stash, git-config

**IN SHORT**

Is there a possibility to create a stash (using `git stash create`) **without** the need to configure `user.email` and `user.name`? Something similar to the `git commit --author` option?

**SOME CONTEXT:**

I have several build machines on which I have a build user. Each has acces to the central git repositories. However I haven't configured `user.email` and `user.name` for each of those users; since they never need to make commits.

In one of my scripts I use

```
git stash create
```

(which allows me to use git archive --format-gtz ... I'll spare you the detail; see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115777/git-archive-with-unstaged-changes))

However this command fails:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <macq@chmalap.macqel>) not allowed
Cannot save the current index state
```

PS: I have git 1.8.4

Comment: If you can upgrade to a more recent Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), `git stash` will tolerate missing user identity. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058474/6309).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With Git's `-c` flag, configuration parameters can be passed on the command line:

```
git -c user.name=test -c user.email=test@test.com stash create
```

Comment: You can also probably use the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` (and same for `COMMITER`) environment variables. [Git-Internals-Environment-Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables)

Comment: `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` are enough for git stash to work.

Answer (score 5):

With Git 2.21 (Q1 2019, 2+ years later), you won't have to configure `user.email` and `user.name` (`git stash --author ?`).

A properly configured username/email is required under `user.useConfigOnly` in order to create commits; **now "`git stash`" (even though it creates commit objects to represent stash entries) command is exempt from the requirement**.

See [commit 3bc2111](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bc2111fc2e9e8ff33b48bb2ccd17b77ca7dbced) (18 Nov 2018) by [Slavica Djukic (``)](https://github.com/).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1328d29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1328d29943c81602bedba085e8c41acf01b4c866), 04 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `stash`: tolerate missing user identity
>
> The "`git stash`" command insists on having a usable user identity to the same degree as the "`git commit-tree`" and "`git commit`" commands do, because it uses the same codepath that creates commit objects as these commands.
>
> It is not strictly necessary to do so.
>
> Check if we will barf before creating commit objects and then supply fake identity to please the machinery that creates commits.
>   Add test to document that stash executes correctly both with and without valid ident.
>
> This is not that much of usability improvement, as the users who run "`git stash`" would eventually want to record their changes that are temporarily stored in the stashes in a more permanent history by committing, and they must do "`git config user.{name,email}`" at that point anyway, so arguably this change is only delaying a step that is necessary to work in the repository.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to remove any local changes from the working copy and **you are sure that there's nothing that needs to be saved for later**, you could run the *disturbingly dangerous* command:

```
git checkout .
```

---

This question could be useful more broadly than just `git stash create` (the issue applies to any use of `git stash`). The question that I answered would probably be a dup of this question.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to my question?

Comment: @ChrisMaes:  It solves a problem that you might otherwise use `git stash` for (removing local changes), and it doesn't have the limitation of requiring user data.

Comment: As I noted in my question, I have no need to remove my changes. I really need to keep them...